# ifconfig is showing etho an wlan but no lo?

Tags: rpi-source

I attempted to give my RPi a static IP address by altering `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Now the command, `ifconfig`, shows no `lo` when called. What did I do wrong?

I tried reverting the line `iface eth0 inet static` back to `iface eth0 inet dhcp`, but still am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

For the loopback device you need the following lines in /etc/network/interfaces.

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```